# How to reference a cell in an external Excel file based on a variable?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel File (**A**) and a cell in it that is equal to another cell in another file (**B**).

Excel file (**B**) is named `2010 something.xls`;

I also have cell (**C**) containing `'[2010 something.xls]test'!$K$224`

I want to have a variable with the current year stored in a cell.

Then cell (**C**) will change its reference based on the year; So in 2011 instead of looking for the `2010 something.xls` will be looking for `2011 something.xls`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "maintains the year". Does it maintain the year from the referenced source? The original source? The current year?

Comment: [This](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/) could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use INDIRECT function/method https://www.google.pt/search?q=INDIRECT+excel .

Comment: You can also concatenate data. `="[" & A1 & "something.xls]test'!$K$224"`. However function is usually more user-friendly way to do it ;)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your 2011 value is stored in cell A1, then, in some other cell, you could try this formula:  ="'[" & A1 & " something.xls]test'!$K$224"

Comment: this just makes a string.. i dont get the referenced value

Comment: Just found it: use INDIRECT function/method

Comment: yeah...sorry; I meant to include the INDIRECT idea !  (No, really!)

Comment: still so not solves my problem because I need this to work even if the worksheet is closed

Answer (score 0):

This will work for referencing another file, workbook and sheet.  The other file must remain open for this to work.

```
=INDIRECT("'["&B6&"]"&C6&"'!"&D6)
```