# Need help referencing external (another drive) sheet using a variable in the reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to reference a cell in an external sheet that is on another drive. I want the reference to include a variable for the year, so that using the reference on sheet A will pull data from
'P:\metrics[Analysis_2022.xlsx]lead_tracking'!AB$1 (sheet B) this year, then next year sheet A will pull data from 'P:\metrics[Analysis_2023.xlsx]lead_tracking'!AB$1 (sheet C), etc. The year is located in cell R1 on sheet A.

I referred to the thread [how-to-reference-a-cell-in-an-external-excel-file-based-on-a-variable](https://superuser.com/questions/252327/how-to-reference-a-cell-in-an-external-excel-file-based-on-a-variable) and think I'm using it correctly, but I'm obviously missing something, (probably something dumb) as I keep getting a #REF error when using the following formula:

INDIRECT("'P:\metrics[Analysis_" & R1 & ".xlsx]lead_tracking'!AB$1")

I'm stuck and need some help please! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct behavior of the [**INDIRECT() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

[image: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261]

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the other workbook was open, but we still get the #REF! error.

Comment: @heyjohnboy Is the address written exactly as it is in your question? It seems to me that there is a missing backslash before the opening square bracket (between the folder name and the workbook name)

Comment: Sorry, it looks this site is dropping the bracket for some reason, but I did include it. 

After further investigation it looks like this issue is somehow related to my hardware configuration. If I open sheet A and sheet B on the same machine the INDIRECT function works fine. But when I open sheet A remotely over VPN, it no longer works. This is interesting, because when using sheet A remotely:

'P:\metrics\[Digital_Lead_Analysis_2022.xlsx]SEO_Resolver'!AB$1 works fine, but

INDIRECT("'P:\metrics\[Digital_Lead_Analysis_" & R126 & ".xlsx]SEO_Resolver'" &  "!AB$1") does not.